# PHP inherit global variable in Anonymous functions

Tags: php, laravel-5, closures, anonymous-function, laravel-excel

I can't use variable `$data` in Anonymous functions:

```
$data = array(...);
Excel::create('Filename',function($excel){
  foreach($data as $v){
     //...
  }
});
```

I get error: "Undefined variable: $data"

Also:

```
 $data = array(...);
 Excel::create('Filename',function($excel){
   global $data;
   foreach($data as $v){
      //...
   }
 });
```

I get error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

How I can use `$data` in Anonymous function?

Comment: `function($excel) use ($data)`

Comment: show your $data = array(...); declaration code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `use` with `closure` as below,

```
$data = array(...);
Excel::create('Filename',function($excel) use ($data){
  foreach($data as $v){
     //...
  }
});
```